# Imagebutton -> calls number doesnt work, eclipse shows no mistake

Tags: android, eclipse, call, imagebutton

Updated Program does what it should now. Thanks alot everyone!

There is this program im writing. Its supposed to show an imagebutton, when its pushed the programm should call a specific phone number. Eclipse doesnt return any errors. But when i run it on the emulator or my phone it quits without any explanation other than unfortunately srshelper (<- the prgram name) has stopped.

Here is the main java-class:

```
package com.example.srshelper;

import com.example.srshelper.R;


import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton froschButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        froschButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibFrosch);

        froschButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"023588778600"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

heres the activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibFrosch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/frosch"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the picture "frosch" lies in the drawable folder. 
HALP! ;)

hey, thanks for the quick response. The logcat reports a missing file:

```
06-18 21:30:29.005: E/Trace(805): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-18 21:30:29.105: W/ActivityThread(805): Application com.example.srshelper is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
06-18 21:30:29.215: I/System.out(805): Sending WAIT chunk
06-18 21:30:29.435: I/dalvikvm(805): Debugger is active
06-18 21:30:29.635: I/System.out(805): Debugger has connected
06-18 21:30:29.635: I/System.out(805): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-18 21:30:29.845: I/System.out(805): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-18 21:30:30.045: I/System.out(805): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-18 21:30:30.255: I/System.out(805): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-18 21:30:30.455: I/System.out(805): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-18 21:30:30.655: I/System.out(805): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-18 21:30:30.855: I/System.out(805): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-18 21:30:31.065: I/System.out(805): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-18 21:30:31.265: I/System.out(805): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-18 21:30:31.465: I/System.out(805): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-18 21:30:31.675: I/System.out(805): debugger has settled (1431)
```

considering the permission, just doublecheked that ones again :D but it seems to be setup correcty. Heres the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.srshelper"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.srshelper.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Allright, some more research led me to a mysterious permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

After including that, the missing file error doesnt show up anymore, instead it reports some other errors. Going to look into them now :D.

```
06-19 09:25:31.903: I/Process(864): Sending signal. PID: 864 SIG: 9
06-19 09:35:22.192: D/AndroidRuntime(964): Shutting down VM
06-19 09:35:22.192: W/dalvikvm(964): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.srshelper/com.example.srshelper.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.example.srshelper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-19 09:35:22.212: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Try debugging it instead of running it, and when it fails check the Logcat and Debug views in Eclipse to get more info about what happened.  Then post it here if needed.

Comment: Debugged as u mentioned. Also created a new project, copy pasted all the code, with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess is that you're missing the permission for making calls in your AndroidManifest

Comment: Permission is in the manifest. Unless im using the wrong perm?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

`ImageButton` is not a `Button`. Your `froschButton` type is not consistent between code and layout.

Comment: Thanks alot, really brought me forward.